# adjacentElementsProduct task in CodeSignal problem - java

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this for 2 hours. That's task:
Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

Example

For inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3], the output should be
adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21.

7 and 3 produce the largest product.

And that's my solution.

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {

    int[] tab = new int[29];
    int len = inputArray.length;

    for(int a = 0, int b = 1; a < len; a++, b++)
    {
        tab[a] = inputArray[a] * inputArray[b];
    }

    int max = -100;

    for(int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] > max)
            max = tab[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

[image: That's screen with errors]

Sure, i could find another (probably shorter) solution, but I'm curious why mine isn't working. Thanks.

EDIT: Warning was because we are starting arrays from 0, not 1. So in my loops it will be
inputArray.length - 1 
instead of 
inputArray.length
I also tried to solve this another way, and that's my 2 solutions:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {

    int[] tab = new int[inputArray.length - 1];

    for(int a = 0; a < inputArray.length - 1; a++)
    {
        tab[a] = inputArray[a] * inputArray[a+1];
    }

    int max = -10000000;

    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (max < tab[i])
            max = tab[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```

And the second:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {
    int wynik = -1000;
    int mnozenie;
    for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++){
        mnozenie = inputArray[i] * inputArray[i+1];
        if(mnozenie > wynik)
            wynik = mnozenie;
    }
    return wynik;
}
```

but thanks for help @cricket_007 & @AhmadWabbi :)

Comment: Remove the `int` before the declaration of b

Comment: You could try converting the for loop into `while(a < len)`... Two variables in a for loop always is hard to read

Comment: for(int a = 0, int b = 1; a < len; a++, b++)
    {
        tab[a] = inputArray[a] * inputArray[b];
    }
    
    changed to:

        int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    
    
    while(a < inputArray.length)
    {
        tab[a] = inputArray[a] * inputArray[b];
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    and that's even better :)
        https://imgur.com/a/BRlJorH @cricket_007

Comment: Well, you started `b=1`, and you're trying to access `inputArray[b]` meanwhile `a` started at 0... Perhaps you meant `b<inputArray.length`?

Answer (score 0):

Java one-liner Solution , make use of map function

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {

    return IntStream.range(1, inputArray.length).map(i->inputArray[i]*inputArray[i-1]).max().getAsInt();

}
```

JavaScript one-liner Solution

```
    function adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) {        

        return Math.max(...arr.slice(1).map((x,i)=>[x*arr[i]]))

    }
```

Comment: Please do upvote as I have posted Java solution and all test cases passed